# Without playing with "border" option of "standalone", how to remove the top white space?

Tags: math-mode, margins, standalone

Without playing with `border` option of `standalone`, how to remove the top white space?

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\[
F(V, T) = E(V) + D(T)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't add parts of an existing answer to your question without explicitly stating that the problem still exist with it. Especially not after months. It would have been better if you would have commented on the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `baselineskip` to `0pt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}%
\baselineskip=0pt%
\[
F(V, T) = E(V) + D(T)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Every now and then things are just too simple...